# Architecture Difference using DirectX and a Qt Widget -- Works one way but not another

Tags: c++, qt, directx

I have the following structure that works and renders a direct x scene to a Qt Widget using the QtSDK vs 4.8.

```
main.cpp---->QGraphicsView---->QGraphicsScene
|
V
DXWidget(override paint engine, contains a d3d9device)
```

Now I don't want to have to decide which of the two device I use in my main function so I have come up with the following architecture.

```
main.cpp
|
V
MyMainWindow (inherits from QMainWindow)-->GLWidget-->GraphicsView-->GraphicsScene
|
V
DXWidget (contains a DX Device)
```

Now the OpenGL rendering cycle still works; however the DirectX rendering cycle does not work using this architecture. The screen renders now as grey. I thought that it might be because I had not overridden the `paintEngine()` method in `MyMainWindow` so I added the following logic to the MyMainWindow.

```
QPaintEngine *TFWMainWindow::paintEngine()
{
#ifdef WIN32
    if (m_renderMode == DIRECTX)
        return NULL;
    else if (m_renderMode == OPENGL)
        QMainWindow::paintEngine();
#elif __linux__
    QMainWindow::paintEngine();
#endif
}
```

However, this still did not help. OpenGL still renders using Qt's graphics scene and graphics view, however the DirectX will still not render correctly. I also have `paintEngine()` overloaded on my WidgetDX but it does not work. Any thoughts as to how to get DirectX to work under the new architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add virtual and const to painEngine()

That is:

```
virtual PaintEngine* paintEngine(...) const
{
   return NULL;
}
```

You only have to do this at the widget level.